# .NET Code sample to find out what is wrong in the code

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this anonymous question that I am trying to solve (It's an online sample question)... and I am not sure what the issue is with the code...

```
for (var i = (DateTime?) startDate; i <= startDate.AddMonths(11); i = i.GetValueOrDefault().AddMonths(1))
{
   var scm = new ScorecardMonth { 
        TheMonth = i, 
        Scorecards = new List<Scorecard>() 
    };
    scm.Scorecards.AddRange(scorecards.FindAll(a => a.TheMonth = i).OrderBy(b => b.GoalType)); 
    scorecardMonths.Add(scm); 
}
```

a.) In the above code, I am not sure what (DateTime?) startDate means?

b.) scorecardMonths on the very last line... sees to be some object List..

c.) The question online says, what is wrong with the code? To me, other than the == sign on the 2nd to last line a=>a.TheMonth == i, I don't see anything else.

Comment: `var i = (DateTime?) startDate` declares a `Nullable` DateTime variable named `i`.  There is no way to tell from this code what `scoreCardMonths` is for sure, but it looks like some kind of `List`.

Comment: thanks. I am not sure why my question is being marked down. I legitimately didn't understand some of the aspects of the code. and yes you are right... the code is so random...

Comment: This part `scorecards.FindAll(a => a.TheMonth = i)` should've been written with double equal signs `scorecards.FindAll(a => a.TheMonth == i)`, is it a *typo*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a.) In the above code, I am not sure what (DateTime?) startDate means?

This is saying cast `startDate` to a `DateTime?` object. `startDate` might be a DateTime and for purposes of this for loop, it's being cast to a nullable DateTime (`DateTime?`)

> b.) scorecardMonths on the very last line... sees to be some object..

Agreed, it looks to be a list, which the `.Add` implies it's a `List< ScorecardMonth>`

> c.) The question online says, what is wrong with the code? Line #5... Scorecards doesn't have an object name... I would like to know if anything else stands out?

I'd throw out the whole thing and start over. I kind of understand what it's doing, but it's written in a difficult to understand way - this seems easier for me to understand, ymmv:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
{
    month = startDate.AddMonths(i);
    var scm = new ScorecardMonth { 
                        TheMonth = month, //this is a DateTime..
                        Scorecards = new List<Scorecard>()
    };

    scorecardsInMonth = scorecards.FindAll(a => a.TheMonth == month)
                                  .OrderBy(b => b.GoalType));
    scm.Scorecards.AddRange(scorecardsInMonth);

    scorecardMonths.Add(scm);
}
```

Comment: can a List be initialized as written above "Scorecards = new List<Scorecard>() ?? 

Also, it still does''t say what is wrong in the above code? As per the code you rewrote everything seems fine... lol

Comment: I cannot throw out and rewrite the code... I want to find out what is wrong with the current way of the code?